# Global var accesible only by redeclare with "global"

Tags: joomla

I have Joomla and some external php scripts and libraries. There is a main library where I declare some global vars.

lib.php

```
global $var_glb; $var_glb="some_value";
```

script.php:

```
require_once(lib.php);
print_r($var_glb) //Notice: Undefined variable
print_r$GLOBALS['var_glb']); //DEFINED!
global $var_glb; print_r($var_glb) //DEFINED!
```

So I had to put "global" in front of $var_glb in order to be accessible... normally it should be defined without "global"...

I don't know why $var_glb (without "global") is lost and only $GLOBALS['var_glb'] is accessible or when using "global $var_glb"

Why is that happening? I don't want to redeclare all global vars in the script.

Comment: Hmmm. There is a comment regarding similar behaviour in the php-docs on scope: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#100884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **Jumi**  component in order to insert php scripts into Joomla.
And the problem with global vars was related to **Jumi**.

I tried another similar component called **Sourcerer** and now everything is working ok.